# Why Virtual machines are not connecting after hadoop installation?

Tags: hadoop, vmware, hortonworks-data-platform

I have downloaded more than 3 times Hortonworks Hadoop on my mac. (Virtual Box and VMWare)

The installation was totally perfect. I was working on it was fast everything was OK but when I turned off and turned on again, it is not working. This screenshot is after my 3rd installation more than half an hour but still waiting.

What is wrong I am doing? 
Thank you for advice.

[image]